# VelocityEngine : Template resource not found

Tags: java, classloader, velocity

I am able to access the templates when I run my project locally in eclipse using a Wildfly server. However, it fails to find the templates when I run it on my prod server.

My vm templates sits in a package  : **com.email.templates**

I've checked the WEB-INF folder and I can see that the templates are sitting in :

```
myapp.war\WEB-INF\classes\com\email\templates\
```

I initialize my VelocityEngine with the following properties :

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.put(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "class");
prop.put("class.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
this.velocityEngine.init(prop);
```

I've tried both of the following methods when trying to fetch them template :

via **org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineUtils**

```
  Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
  model.put("payload", "some payload");
  String body = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(this.velocityEngine , "/com/email/templates/my_template.vm", model);
```

via **org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine**

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("payload", "some payload")
Template template = this.velocityEngine.getTemplate("/com/email/templates/my_template.vm");
template.merge(context, writer);
```

Comment: Are you using `Maven`? . Look like your  path incorrect definitely .

Comment: I added prop.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.CommonsLogLogChute") . This seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your template not in the classpath You should have template in resources folder rather than `web app` . This is to work I believe You need to have `WebappResourceLoader`

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("resource.loader", "webapp");
props.setProperty("myapp.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader");
props.setProperty("webapp.resource.loader.path", "classes\com\email\templates");
VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine(props);
```

EDIT: If you are loading from Resources folder always use below code:

```
velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "class,file");
velocityEngine.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS, "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.Log4JLogChute");
velocityEngine.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.logger", "VELLOGGER");
velocityEngine.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
velocityEngine.setProperty("runtime.log.logsystem.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.NullLogSystem");
```